# Does the Pope talk with God?

Tags: papacy, pope-francis, visions

We know that visionaries, such as [them](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Medjugorje), talk/talked with the Virgin Mary or God.

But does the Pope directly talk with God or the Virgin Mary? Or, does he do it in any other, not-direct, way? Is it the same for any precedent Pope?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Not all questions work well in our format.  For example, questions that are primarily opinion-based.  When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  This is how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809

Comment: I hope [this music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Gx1Pv02w3Q) isn't your source for the question.

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by "directly talk with God". Do you mean "Does a pope pray to God?" or "Does the Holy Ghost favor every pope with extraordinary gifts like prophecy or visions?"

Comment: A better question is “Does God talk to the pope?” All who pray are talking to God are they not?

Answer (score 1):

> But does the Pope directly talk with God or the Virgin Mary? Or, does he do it in any other, not-direct, way?

First, notice that God is Trinitarian, so anyone "speaking" to God must speak to one of the three persons, either God the Father, Jesus or the Holy Spirit.

Now, regarding visions or other forms of visitations, if we are to believe the apocryphal [Acts of Peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_Peter), then Peter himself (the First pope) was the only Pope in history of which we have recollection to have directly talked to God (as Jesus). There seems to be [no other account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visions_of_Jesus_and_Mary) of such encounter.

Regarding talking to God in "other, not-direct, way", of course! That's what prayer is all about. Jesus taught us and encouraged us to pray to God the Father. He Himself gave us the example of such prayer. Thus, this is not limited to popes but open to every Christian. We can also direct our prayers/conversation to Jesus and the Holy Spirit.

Now, it is only us (so far as I know) who speak in terms of words to God. God might respond in multiple, sometimes unexpected ways, to our prayers and questions. Many times we are so busy and anxious with the daily tolls of life that there is no enough silence in our hearts/souls in order to listen to God.

Answer (score 0):

The Pope has no special way of talking to God. In Mat 6:9-13 Jesus taught his disciples how to talk to God, one of whom was Peter, the founder of the Papacy. However, everyone has direct access to God and able to talk to Him at anytime, anywhere.

As for the visionaries, you can be certain to discount every one of them. The Bible defines the standard of visions, which is concrete and specific. Vague claims that lead to nothing but belief in the apparition itself is not from God. Most visitations result in extreme fear, pralysis, and near death (Eze 1:28-2:3; Dan 10:7-11; Rev 1:17). Others appear normal but carry a specific purpose (Gen 18:9-15). If neither are present you should be very skeptical.

Comment: According to Catholicism, Peter was not the founder of the Papacy. This comes from Jesus Himself.

Comment: My understanding is the papacy was derived from Mat 16:18, 19. (Mat 16:18)  And I say also unto thee, That thou art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it.
(Mat 16:19)  'And I will give unto thee the keys of the kingdom of heaven: and whatsoever thou shalt bind on earth shall be bound in heaven: and whatsoever thou shalt loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven.'

Comment: Indeed. It is Jesus who builds his Church upon Peter, not Peter building it upon himself. It is Jesus who gives the keys of the kingdom to Peter, and not Peter assigning the keys to himself. Peter is acted upon by Jesus. This is different from Peter saying "ok lads, I am building a church. Follow me."

Comment: Well I wasn't implying Peter started a different religion. Jesus gave Peter the authority to build the church as he saw fit, or am I missing something?

Comment: Jesus says "upon this rock **I will build** my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it. (Mat 16:19) 'And **I will give unto thee** the keys of the kingdom of heaven:". It is not Peter who builds (and thus not him who founds the Papacy, according to Catholicism), but Jesus.

Comment: Jesus wasn't around to build the church which is why he left Peter in charge. The handing over the keys symbolised the fact Jesus from that point forward could not bind or free either in Earth or Heaven, only Peter could do that. But, of course, Peter acted in the name of Jesus, as we all should do, so in that sense, yes Jesus founded the papacy through Peter.